# PHP / JSON - echo stdClass object when property name is number

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I have stored a JSON ouput into as a stdClass object using json_decode.

Ideally I want to echo the property names and values for the histogram object.

I tried

```
echo $obj->histogram->20000();
```

but it doesn't seem to recognise 20000 because it's a number. Also tried '20000'.

JSON code:

```
{
  "location": {
    "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::Location",
    "display_name": "Melbourne, Melbourne Region",
    "area": [
      "Australia",
      "Victoria",
      "Melbourne Region",
      "Melbourne"
    ]
  },
  "__CLASS__": "Adzuna::API::Response::SalaryHistogram",
  "histogram": {
    "20000": 2,
    "40000": 36,
    "60000": 95,
    "80000": 53,
    "100000": 27,
    "120000": 9,
    "140000": 6
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved it

`echo $json_obj->histogram->{'20000'};`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP variables and class members can be *just about anything*, but *in your PHP code* they have to basically start with a normal ASCII alphabetic character or underscore (more specifically `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff]`, but in practice no one uses all the characters in that range).

To access variables that cannot be accessed using the `$var` format you have to use *variable variables*:

```
$name = "1twøThré3";
$value = $$name;
```

That is the "normal" way to use variable variables. Another way is to pass the name directly to the variable identifier:

```
$value = ${"1twøThré3"}
```

The same applies to object members:

```
$value = $obj->{"1twøThré3"};
```